# Jquery is not adding class to SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, addclass

I'm facing problems in adding class by using .addClass in jquery.
Please help.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 700, 300italic, 400italic, 600, 600italic, 700italic);

/* font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */

* margin:0 padding:0 ouline:none box-sizing:border-box=trans($speed:0.3s) -webkit-transition:all $speed ease -moz-transition:all $speed ease transition:all $speed ease body background:#ffffff color:#666666 font-family:'Open Sans',
sans-serif font-weight:300 .whole-con width:auto height:auto margin:0 auto padding:30px 40px overflow:hidded=div ($width:100%,
$bg-color:#f5f5f5,
$color:#666666,
$float:none,
$margin:0 auto) width:$width background:$bg-color color:$color margin:$margin .main-con +div($bg-color:#1ABC9C)=basic-div width:100% height:auto .header +basic-div .menu-con +basic-div text-align:right .menu-btn cursor:pointer background:#009576 +trans rect -moz-transform-origin:50% 0%;
 -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
 transform-origin:50% 0%;
 opacity:0.9 -moz-transform-style:preserve-3D;
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3D;
 transform-style:preserve-3D;
 +trans .line2 position:absolute &:hover background:#00886b >rect opacity:1 .active rect opacity:1 .line2 -moz-transform:translateX(-100px) -webkit-transform:translateX(-100px) transform:translateX(-100px) opacity:0 .line1 -moz-transform:translateX(4px) rotate(-40deg) -webkit-transform:translateX(4px) rotate(-40deg) transform:translateX(4px) rotate(-40deg) .line3 -moz-transform:translateX(4px) rotate(37.5deg) -webkit-transform:translateX(4px) rotate(37.5deg) transform:translateX(4px) rotate(37.5deg)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--container-->
<div class="whole-con">
  <!--first main con-->
  <div class="main-con">
    <!--header-->
    <div class="header">
      <!--menu-->
      <div class="menu-con">
        <!--menu btn SVG-->
        <svg version="1.1" id="Menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve" class="menu-btn">
          <rect class="line3" x="9" y="14" fill="#f5f5f5" width="32" height="3" />
          <rect class="line2" x="9" y="24" fill="#f5f5f5" width="32" height="3" />
          <rect class="line1" x="9" y="34" fill="#f5f5f5" width="32" height="3" />
        </svg>
        <!--/menu btn SVG-->
      </div>
      <!--/menu-->
    </div>
    <!--/header-->
  </div>
  <!--/first main con-->
</div>
<!--/container-->
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so there's a couple of things you should check: 1. Are you including the jquery library correctly? 2. Is there any broken JS code? Look for exceptions in your browser console.

Comment: This is the Jquery lib i'm using: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: There's also the possibility that you don't have an element with the class `menu-btn`.

Comment: Can you link your HTML please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jjn5w4qv/ Works just fine

Comment: I have.. that's an SVG.. here:
<svg version="1.1" id="Menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                    width="60px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50"
                    enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve" class="menu-btn">

Comment: @technophobia makes a good point.  Always have your developer console open so you can see if any JS errors are being thrown.  1 JS error can often screw up a lot of other things.  I've had this happen to me quite often.

Comment: Why it's not working on my PC? which lib should i use?

Comment: @NajamK can you post a JS Fiddle with your HTML and JS ?

Comment: OK give me min please

Comment: Your code works perfectly, you can verify using this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bazqdf6s/).

Comment: @Chiefwarpaint Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/jjn5w4qv/1/

Comment: Within your click handler, add `alert($(this).html());` - you'll see it's NOT the `<svg>` tag that's becoming `this`  https://jsfiddle.net/jjn5w4qv/2/

Comment: Your fiddle is loading jQuery twice: first because of the Frameworks menu, then because of the `<script>` tag in the HTML. You don't need the tag when you use the menu.

Comment: I don't see anything to click on in the fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar There should be a very dim menu icon to click on.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Maybe you should make it more visible.

Comment: Well i'm using it on green bg..
do you guys have any idea why it's taking "rects" instead of whole SVG ??

Comment: You can download whole folder from here: http://wikisend.com/download/257656/files.zip

Thanks for help!

Comment: @NajamK have a look at that link I pasted above, it will resolve your issue.  It turns out that jQuery can't change class on an `svg`, you'll need to use `.attr()` to change your classes.  Good luck.